# Enable fail2ban to send out emails without installing too much extra software (like postfix)

Tags: debian, email, postfix, sendmail, debian-buster

I need fail2ban to send out email notifications to myself. It runs on a Debian 10 minimal install

All of the tutorials I found simply install the full email packages like Postfix or Sendmail, and move on. Moreover (and if I got it right) for the `mail` command to be available, I also need to install `mailutils`.

With merely those two, here's what I'm looking at:

```
root:~# apt-get install --no-install-recommends sendmail mailutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  guile-2.2-libs libgc1c2 libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 liblockfile1 libltdl7 liblzo2-2 libmailutils5 libmariadb3 libntlm0 libpython2.7 libsigsegv2 lockfile-progs m4 mailutils-common make mariadb-common mysql-common procmail
  sendmail-base sendmail-bin sendmail-cf sensible-mda
Suggested packages:
  m4-doc mailutils-mh mailutils-doc make-doc sendmail-doc rmail logcheck resolvconf sasl2-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  guile-2.2-libs libgc1c2 libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 liblockfile1 libltdl7 liblzo2-2 libmailutils5 libmariadb3 libntlm0 libpython2.7 libsigsegv2 lockfile-progs m4 mailutils mailutils-common make mariadb-common mysql-common procmail
  sendmail sendmail-base sendmail-bin sendmail-cf sensible-mda
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 2525 kB/12.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 63.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

(For Postfix the list is quite similar)

Sure enough I can continue, but my concerns are all the extra packages that I otherwise wouldn't install on this server (e.g. the database software), and the [potential security issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/417702/sendmail-injection) that I otherwise wouldn't have faced. (Sure, I can block port 25, but it's still a few extra things to maintain on the system, times several systems; not having any of that at all seems like a much easier and safer option)

Aliasing Sendmail to go to an external SMTP isn't an option either, because I need this on multiple servers, and delivering and configuring SMTP passwords on each may be a hassle.

Is there a way to make fail2ban send out emails without this much overhead? I don't care if the email looks spammy; I will whitelist the sender server in my inbox to make sure it doesn't go to junk mail. That server will not be sending emails to anyone else.

Apparently, [it's possible to send out an e-mail using just telnet](https://www.unix.com/303000955-post5.html). I was hoping there's a way to have fail2ban be able to do something similar easily - either with a script, or a tiny utility available with `apt-get install`. Am I asking for something realistic, or shut up and get Sendmail is my only option?

Comment: @Lenniey I'm not sure: the other asker specifically doesn't want root@machinename, while I'm fine with it; the accepted answer is about exim4 which is not lightweight; the other answer mentions ssmtp, which [someone else claims is not in active development and therefore not secure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116805/how-to-install-postfix-for-sending-mails-to-admin-only/118101#comment459267_118101)

Comment: Yes, but if you follow the rabbits hole you'll find [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) or just use ssmtp, which is "old", but looks stable enough.

Comment: @Lenniey I did, and I also found `nullmailer`, and all three seem to depend on an external SMTP server, which I explicitly said I wanted to avoid. I'm still looking though if there's a way around that with any of them

Comment: Well, you'll need _some_ mailserver _somewhere_...